# Query fields dynamically in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say the schema is:

```
var Rows = mongoose.model('Rows', {   
    row1: String,
    row2: String
});
```

How would I query one of the rows at random? For example:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.rand() * 2);
Rows.find({ "row" + rand: "sup" }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(result);
});
```

This code get's an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token +`

Comment: The bug is that you can't use the shortcut object creation syntax in the way you're trying. You can't construct a property/field name on the fly that way - it has to be a literal string.

Comment: And, it was pointed out below that the random won't produce the correct results.

Comment: Added an answer with those details and another possibly more expressive way of performing the query using some slick Mongoose functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try like

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.rand() * 2);

var objFind = {};
objFind["row" + rand] = "sup";

Rows.find(objFind, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to give you the expected results

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
```

To get a random number range in JavaScript, you should probably be doing something like this:

```
var randomWithRange = function (min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};
```

To use this in your code

```
var conditions = {};
conditions["row" + randomWithRange(1, 2)] = "sup";

Rows.find(conditions, function(err, result){ ... });
```

Comment: The point of the question isn't the random part of the question. I threw up this code to abstract the question to make it useful for others also.

Comment: Shame on me for providing additional information to someone that's trying to learn how to do something. I suppose I won't waste time telling you why `row1`, `row2`, `rowN` is a bad design, too.

Comment: No need to be bitter, friend.

Thanks for taking your time to answer! =)

Comment: @bzupnick Whether or not it was your focus in asking, it is as aspect of the original snippet that is error-prone. It has a good chance of querying for `row0`, which doesn't appear to exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a JavaScript object by building property names on the fly using the shortcut syntax, they must be literals (strings or numbers):

```
var x = { "row1" : "sup" };
```

You can do this instead:

```
var x = {};
var rowNum = 1;
x["row" + 1] = "sup";
```

However, a more simple Mongoose way to express the query would be to use `where` ([docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.where)):

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.rand() * 2) + 1;
Rows.where("row" + rand, "sup").exec(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(result);
});
```